# Custom page archive query by url var calling page twice on one of my custom queries?

Tags: php, wp-query, taxonomy

This is such an odd issue. I will try and break it down as simply as I can.

I am creating my own custom page query which works like an archive using url variables to customise the query results.

**This is my `getVar()` function...**

```
public static function getVar($name, $default = false) {

    // check our param exists
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {
      return $_REQUEST[$name];
    }

    // return our default value
    return $default;
}
```

**This is my page-products.php entire query...**

```
// get our filter params
$sSearch       = CF::getVar('search', false);
$sCategory     = CF::getVar('cat', false);
$sSweets       = CF::getVar('sweets', false);
$sChocolates   = CF::getVar('chocolate', false);
$sSnacks       = CF::getVar('biscuits-snacks', false);
$sPackaging    = CF::getVar('packaging', false);
$sSorting      = CF::getVar('orderby', 'random');

// build our basic filters
$aFilters = array (
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 100,
    'orderby'           => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'         => array (
        'relation'          => 'AND',
    )
);

// filter by search query
if($sSearch) {
    $aFilters['s'] = $sSearch;
}

// filter by product category
if($sCategory) {
    // extend our filter array
    $aFilters['tax_query'][] = array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'cat',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array ($sCategory),
    );
}

// filter by product sweets
if($sSweets) {
    // extend our filter array
    $aFilters['tax_query'][] = array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'confectionery',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array ($sSweets),
    );
}

// filter by product chocolates
if($sChocolates) {
    // extend our filter array
    $aFilters['tax_query'][] = array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'confectionery',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array ($sChocolates),
    );
}

// filter by product biscuits & snacks
if($sSnacks) {
    // extend our filter array
    $aFilters['tax_query'][] = array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'confectionery',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array ($sSnacks),
    );
}

// filter by product packaging
if($sPackaging) {
    // extend our filter array
    $aFilters['tax_query'][] = array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'packaging',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array ($sPackaging),
    );
}

// sorting select contents array
$aSorting = array (
    'newest'        => 'Latest products',
    'oldest'        => 'Oldest products',
    'product_asc'   => 'Product A-Z',
    'product_desc'  => 'Product Z-A'
);

if(User::logged_in()) {
    // show price sorting in the dropdown
    $aSorting['price_highest']  = 'Price high-low';
    $aSorting['price_lowest']   = 'Price low-high';
}

// determine our sorting filters
switch($sSorting) {

    case 'product_asc':
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'title';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'ASC';
        break;

    case 'product_desc':
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'title';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'DESC';
        break;

    case 'price_highest':
        $aFilters['meta_key']   = 'product_starting_price';
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'DESC';
        break;

    case 'price_lowest':
        $aFilters['meta_key']   = 'product_starting_price';
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'meta_value_num';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'ASC';
        break;

    case 'oldest':
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'date';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'ASC';
        break;

    case 'latest':
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'date';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'DESC';
        break;

    case 'random':
    default:
        $aFilters['orderby']    = 'rand';
        $aFilters['order']      = 'DESC';
        break;
}

// build our product object
$oProducts = new WP_Query($aFilters);
```

So everything above is working absolutely fine. Each query returns the correct results.

However, on the `cat` query, I noticed the page was taking a little longer to load than the other queries.

So I checked my network console and this is what is happening...

```
products?cat=eco-range
```

[image]

As you can see above its loading twice. This doesn't make any sense?

---

See below my network results on my other queries which are all one time, as they should be.

```
products?sweets=millions
```

[image]

```
products?packaging=gift-box-midi
```

[image]

```
products?search=110201
```

[image]

If anyone has any ideas as to why this could be happening or can help me solve this issue. That would be great.

Thanks in advance.

---

Unfortunately Chris's answer did not make any change. See the updated changed

My custom category is now registered as `prod_cat` and my url var is also set to `prod_cat` so not to conflict with the reserved terms.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

Here is my updated query on my **page-products.php**.

```
// get our filter params
$sCategory = CF::getVar('prod_cat', false);

// build our basic filters
$aFilters = array (
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 100,
    'orderby'           => 'ASC',
    'tax_query'         => array (
        'relation'          => 'AND',
    )
);

// filter by product prod_cat
if($sCategory) {
    // extend our filter array
    $aFilters['tax_query'][] = array (
        'taxonomy'  => 'prod_cat',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array ($sCategory),
    );
}
```

And its still loading twice in the network console.

[image]

This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where did you see those Network results? Is it when you visit `?prod_cat=chocolate` ?

Comment: I've literally just figured out what was happening, I'm going to leave an answer shortly but it's probably pointless. I had a typo in my nav walker. So my page is `products` but I was accidentally calling `product`. So the extra network loading was because wordpress was redirecting to the correct page.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then WordPress applied canonical redirect, which is why the redirect happened. But it's a good thing to know, so +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because cat is a reserved query parameter. Try change it to a different name like 'category' or just 'c'.

If you compare the two URLs before and after the redirect, are they the same or changed slightly?

Comment: You're right... I thought `category` was the reserved type all this time. But I guess its just the slug that displays on categories in posts. Thanks https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

Comment: Unfortunately changing the query vars and even the registered taxonomy did not fix this, see my code above.